# Teamcity doesnt run whole custom script

Tags: teamcity

Custom script:

```
%env.USERPROFILE%/Envs/%ProjectName%/Scripts/activate & pip list & do_something*
ECHO testtesttest
ECHO testtesttest
ECHO testtesttest
ECHO testtesttest
ECHO testtesttest
ECHO testtesttest
ECHO testtesttest
ECHO testtesttest
ECHO testtesttest
ECHO testtesttest
ECHO testtesttest
ECHO testtesttest
```

Output has no 'testtesttest' at all,
it just ends with first line exit code 1 (proper value from script) but doesn't give a flying what scropti should do afterwards. Do you have any solutions to that?

*sorry, i cannot show the script command unfortunately, hovever it's basically python inside nad that part works

Comment: is it a shell script?

Comment: no, its python command there, however able to return correct RC

Comment: what is the build step you are using?